# Is there something similar to ipywidgets in R?

Tags: python, r, google-colaboratory, ipywidgets, choropleth

I'm creating choropleths maps in Colab using the R Kernel. And I'd rather create a map with a widget in order to be able to select the map to show.

I have done this previously in Python using the `ipywidgets` package, and now I should do it using R language. So, my question is: is there something similar to `ipywidgets` in R?

Thanks!

Comment: There is R shiny.

Comment: Please see [this](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/choropleths.html) and [this](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/shiny.html) or [this](https://plotly.com/r/choropleth-maps/) and [this](https://plotly-r.com/maps.html).

Comment: @ismirsehregal I'm looking for something like a scrollbar or suchlike. I've been searching for and I've seen that `plotly` allows creating scrollbars, but I don`t know if it's possible for a Spanish regions map.